# Symbols in Spanish numbers

Tags: símbolos

What is the equivalent for the number in Spanish: 1'740.720? I saw this number in an article, but don't understand the ' symbol after the one (1'). It looks like an apostrophe was placed after the number. I understand the punto after the the thousands 1.000.

Answer (score 6):

That apostrophe is simply marking millions. 1'000.000 is one million (1.000.000).

That isn't a standard notation in Spanish (in fact, [it isn't recommended](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/miles-y-millones-claves-de-escritura/)), and other languages also use apostrophes as separators:

> **3. Los millones**
>   No hay un signo especial para los millones, que se marcan igualmente con un espacio. Se desaconsejan, por tanto, grafías como *1’000,000* (con apóstrofo) y *1,000.000* (coma y punto), que se ven ocasionalmente en los medios.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is helpful. One of my Spanish 4 AP students was attempting to comprehend a chart in which the apostrophe type symbol was used. The class thought it might have something to do with millions, but as I had never used this symbol, I was not sure. I let the students know that I would inquire, and give them an explanation upon their return to class.

Comment: @RuthGonzalez I'm glad I could help! Please don't forget that you can mark an answer as correct with the green check button.

Comment: that notation was still used in late 80's and early 90's , THANK GOD!, most editors are finally adopting the standard notation